# Prevent calling global function for each same element on the same page when 'click' event is invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery-events, razor-pages

I encountered a problem having two buttons `removeButton` with the same selector `$("div[data-lookup-entity-type=some_type] .js-lookup-clear");`on a page.

[image]

[image]

So when I am clicking on 'X' (clear) button then two confirmation dialog appears (screen below):

[image]

That is the code that registers `click` event when 'X' button is being actually clicked:

```
var removeButton = $("div[data-lookup-entity-type=some_type] .js-lookup-clear");

removeButton.on("click", function () {

    var accessGroupControl = $("div[data-lookup-entity-type=some_type] input[type='hidden']");
    var selectedAccessGroup = accessGroupControl.val();

    if (isStringUndefinedOrNullOrEmpty(selectedAccessGroup)) {

        return true;
    }

    app.confirm.showConfirmation({

        text: "some text",
        caption: "some caption",
        resolveButtonText: "Yes",
        rejectButtonText: "No",
        reverse: true
    }).then(function () {

        removeButton.unbind("click");
        removeButton.click();
    });

    return false;
});
```

I assume that having two identical buttons (I mean same selectors: `$("div[data-lookup-entity-type=AccessCode] .js-lookup-clear");`) causes the confirmation dialog call twice.

I was trying to tackle with binding of `showConfirmation` that was partially successful: there's been invoked just one confirmation dialog, but for any reason the value in the input element was cleared.

Is there any other options to solve that problem without any changes in HTML or something? Or may be the problem is not even in a global `showConfirmation` function or a callback itself?

Comment: Can you identify a unique relationship between the button and the elements it needs to remove, and/or  a definition of the action it should take?  Updating the post with a minimal  (contrived) HTML example would help readers immensely.

Comment: Sure, I added a couple screens to show literally what the problem is. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in the update although it was not what I was expecting. In any case please check my answer for what is causing the problem. For future reference, please do not post images of code for reasons given in this [obscure and hard to find META post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5217142).

Answer (score 1):

The problem code:

```
removeButton.click();
```

In this statement (inside the `then` handler after `showConfirmation()`),
`removeButton` is a jQuery collection containing multiple elements. Calling [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click) on the collection clicks all elements in the collection.

What seems to be missing is code to identify and remember the HTML element clicked, before calling `showConfirmation`. While unable to provide code to fit the actual app's architecture, I suggest starting by renaming `removeButton` to `removeButtons` as the first step.

Comment: Thanks for help, but eventually it's been decided (NOT SURPRISINGLY) to take the parent element which, in turn, has a unique `id` attribute and then find child `.js-lookup-clear` and register an event. Well, feel quite stupid, but seems to be working.